# Javascript replacing string pattern using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I want to remove any occurances of the string pattern of a number enclosed by square brackets, e.g. [1], [25], [46], [345] (I think up to 3 characters within the brackets should be fine). I want to replace them with an empty string, "", i.e. remove them.

I know this can be done with regular expressions but I'm quite new to this. Here's what I have which doesn't do anything:

```
var test = "this is a test sentence with a reference[12]";
removeCrap(test);
alert(test);

function removeCrap(string) {

var pattern = new RegExp("[...]"); 
string.replace(pattern, "");
```

}

Could anyone help me out with this? Hope the question is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. `[]` has a special meaning in regular expressions, it creates a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). If you want to match these characters literally, you have to escape them.
2. [`replace` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the *first* occurrence of a string/expression, unless you set the global flag/modifier.
3. `replace` **returns** the new string, it does not change the string in-place.

Having this in mind, this should do it:

```
var test = "this is a test sentence with a reference[12]";
test = test.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '');
alert(test);
```

Regular expression explained:

In JavaScript, `/.../` is a *regex literal*. The `g` is the global flag.

- `\[` matches `[` literally
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `\]` matches `]` literally

To learn more about regular expression, have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: @maxcollins: My pleasure :) Welcome to SO and don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most (by clicking the tick outline next to it).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
test = test.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '');
```

- `\[` because `[` on its own introduces a character range
- `\d+`  - any number of digits
- `\]` as above
- `/g` - do it for every occurrence

NB: you have to reassign the result (either to a new variable, or back to itself) because `String.replace` doesn't change the original string.