# Proofreading Text with JavaScript and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I proofread a lot of plaintext files submitted by peers. As my eyes get tired I sometimes overlook extra spaces, or duplicate words. I currently use the following RegEx searches:

```
[/t]{2} -Finds duplicate spaces  
(?>(/p{P})\1+)(?<![^.]|^)\.{3}) -Finds duplicate punctuation except ellipses  
\b(\w+)\s+\1\b -Finds duplicate words
```

I also have a few custom searches, example find "Mister" and replace with "Mr."

Is there a simple way to execute these four types of replace functions in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript replacing string pattern using RegExp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558972/javascript-replacing-string-pattern-using-regexp)

Comment: The two first patterns are false. where are the replacement strings?

Comment: I started with a simple solution, using [Workflow for iOS](https://workflow.is). There I am using the above examples and the replacement string is $1, or for the first example I just have it replace with a single space.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Javascript supports regular expressions, so learn how to use the API and use it. If you have a specific problem, ask a question. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) has a good article, but there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two regex don't look very good.
You could combine them all into a single regex though.

Of the two types below:

Type - 1 uses the `punct` posix character class.
Type - 2 uses a `Branch Reset` construct and the `Punct` property construct.

Just do a global find/replace with whichever regex will work with your platform.

Type 1 -

```
 # Find:  (?:([^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]+|\b(\w+)(?:\s+\2)+\b|(\.{3})\.*|([[:punct:]])\4+)
 # Replace:  $1$2$3$4

 (?:
      ( [^\S\r\n] )                 # (1)
      [^\S\r\n]+ 
   |  
      \b 
      ( \w+ )                       # (2)
      (?: \s+ \2 )+
      \b 
   |  
      ( \.{3} )                     # (3)
      \.*
   |  
      ( [[:punct:]] )               # (4)
      \4+ 
 )
```

Type 2 -

```
 # Find:  (?|([^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]+|\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b|(\.{3})\.*|(\p{Punct})\1+)
 # Replace:  $1

 (?|
      ( [^\S\r\n] )                 # (1)
      [^\S\r\n]+ 
   |  
      \b 
      ( \w+ )                       # (1)
      (?: \s+ \1 )+
      \b 
   |  
      ( \.{3} )                     # (1)
      \.*
   |  
      ( \p{Punct} )                 # (1)
      \1+ 
 )
```